# Three.js renderer.autoClear property not working?

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to make the renderer write on top of the previous frame. If I understand the context of autoClear correct, renderer.autoClear = false; should make this possible, however I can't seem to make it work.

Here is a codepen example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ifLEz?editors=001

```
renderer.autoClear = false;
```

If I'm missing a point, feel free to fork it and paste the solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true, preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, then what does .autoClear do?