# What is the reason for having both preserveDrawingBuffer and autoClear renderer properties?

Tags: three.js

The renderer will clear its output before rendering even if `autoClear` is set to false due to the fact that the constructor property `preserveDrawingBuffer` is set to false by default.

Both of these properties can control whether or not the renderer clears before rendering output. They both also conflict with each other (if one is false, the other must be true, or vice versa).

Is there a reason for having two properties of the renderer doing the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are separate issues.

`renderer.autoClear = false` is appropriate if you have [multiple render passes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309289/three-js-geometry-in-top-of-another/13309722#13309722), or if you are doing post-processing with `THREE.EffectComposer` and [`BloomPass`](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_lines_colors.html), for example.

`preserveDrawingBuffer` is required if, for example, if you [require persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26362816/three-js-renderer-autoclear-property-not-working) for some reason.

EDIT: `preserveDrawingBuffer = true` is [not required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30647502/1461008) to take a screenshot.

three.js r.87