# How to toggle preserveDrawingBuffer in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Basically, I want the setup where I could go to preserveDrawingBuffer=true, render the scene once, grab the screenshot, and go back. However, this poses two problems:

- there is no method in renderer to dispose all the buffers,
- canvas goes black if I do

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas:renderer.domElement,preserveDrawingBuffer:true});

How do I do this properly?

EDIT: I did not find the way to toggle this, so I had to clone scene and create second renderer instead to make the screenshot. See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/189

Comment: why would you want to toggle it?

Comment: As gaitat asked, why do you need to toggle it?  You don't need preserveDrawingBuffer=true to grab screenshots.

Comment: preserveDrawingBuffer=true causes rendering bugs on some machines, preserveDrawingBuffer=false makes screenshots all black

Comment: I believe @gman is correct. With `preserveDrawingBuffer` set to `false`, try re-rendering immediately prior, like so: `renderer.render( scene, camera ); var dataUrl = renderer.domElement.toDataURL( "image/jpeg" );`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You don't need `preserveDrawingBuffer: true` to take a screenshot. What you need is to take the screenshot immediately after rendering. A screenshot is guaranteed to work as long as you take it after rendering but before exiting the current event.

So for example this will always work

```
renderer.render( scene, camera );
var screenshot = renderer.domElement.toDataURL();
```

Whereas this will only work randomly if you're luck

```
someElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
   // this is not immediately after rendering. you have no
   // idea when it is relative to rendering.
   var screenshot = renderer.domElement.toDataURL();
});
```

Most of the THREE.js examples have a render function if you need to take a screenshot when the user requests one you could do this

```
someElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
   render();
   var screenshot = renderer.domElement.toDataURL();
});
```

Or you could do this

```
var takeScreenshot;

function render() {
   ...
   if (takeScreenshot) {
     takeScreenshot = false;
     var screenshot = renderer.domElement.toDataURL();
   }
}

someElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
   takeScreenshot = true;
});
```

Or any number of other ways to just make sure you take the screenshot immediately after rendering.

Comment: Do you have a source for "guaranteed to work as long as you take it after rendering but before exiting the current event"? I'm curious if that's actually guaranteed by the WebGL specification.

Comment: Thank you for this answer!!  I was not excited about having to set `preserveDrawingBuffer` to `true` so this was a great solution!  Even works with post-processing!

Answer (score 1):

I have also encountered this problem.my screenshot is blank in threejs webgl canvas, because not set renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas:renderer.domElement,preserveDrawingBuffer:true});,
Here is my way to toggle preserveDrawingBuffer.

```
let canvas = this.renderer.domElement;
    canvas.getContext('webgl' , {preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
this.render();
var data = {
  image: canvas.toDataURL(),
};
canvas.getContext('webgl' , {preserveDrawingBuffer: false});
```

Comment: Which browser do change the CanvasContext's init options like that? If it really does work on one of your browsers, that's a bug. (Ps: tried on FF and Chrome on osX and it doesn't work.)

Comment: Yes,I'm wrong and you are right, the context only can first init, cannot change anymore, and in my situation, " this.render()" can solve my problem, and I will continue to investigate the solution.