# SOI not found from saved canvas image

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, jpeg

I have an experimental application using `Three.js`, in which I am allowing the user to save a diagram he draws on a `canvas` element as a JPEG.  I am doing so by using:

```
<a id="download" download="PathPlanner.jpg">Download as image</a>

function download() {
var dt = canvas.toDataURL('PathPlanner/jpeg');
this.href = dt;
}
document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click', download, false);
```

while making sure that

```
preserveDrawingBuffer: true
```

This works fine, and the saved `jpeg` image may look something like this:

[image]

I am then experimenting with [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-from-image), which accepts an image and finds the shortest distance between two points following any particular line color. `Path-from-image` package uses [jpeg-js](https://github.com/eugeneware/jpeg-js) to encode and decode images.

As far as I know the 0th and first bytes of a JPEG image are always 0xFF and 0xD8, 
However, I keep getting the following error on the saved `.jpg` image file:

> Uncaught Error: SOI not found at constructor.parse

I am using the example code from `path-from-image` package to test it's functionality in my application. The code is:

```
        const fs = require('fs');
        const jpeg = require('jpeg-js');
        const PathFromImage = require('path-from-image');

        const redPointCoords = [0, -16];
        const bluePointCoords = [0, 0];

        const image = jpeg.decode(fs.readFileSync('Images/PathPlanner.jpg'), true);
        const pathFromImage = new PathFromImage({
            width: image.width,
            height: image.height,
            imageData: image.data,
            colorPatterns: [{ r: [128], g: [128], b: [128] }], // 
             description of the gray color
        });
        const path = pathFromImage.path(redPointCoords, bluePointCoords);
        console.log(path);
```

The error is pointing to `const image = jpeg.decode(fs.readFileSync(''), true);`

While the error is generated here:

```
        var fileMarker = readUint16();
        if (fileMarker != 0xFFD8) { // SOI (Start of Image)
            throw new Error("SOI not found");
        }
```

This is [Line 598 in jpeg-js/lib/decoder.js.](https://github.com/eugeneware/jpeg-js/blob/master/lib/decoder.js#L597)

The package works well with other images but not with the image I am allowing the user to save.

Any pointers on how to overcome this issue?

Comment: The documentation about [`.toDataUrl()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) says: _canvas.toDataURL(type, encoderOptions);_ . In your example of code `var dt = canvas.toDataURL('PathPlanner/jpeg');`, what does _'PathPlanner/jpeg'_ mean?

Comment: @prisoner849, that was it! Excellent catch, overlooked that for a moment. Would happily accept your answer if you decided to write it down.

Comment: FYI: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30628064/how-to-toggle-preservedrawingbuffer-in-three-js/30647502#30647502

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation about [.toDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) says: *canvas.toDataURL(type, encoderOptions);*. In your example of code,

```
var dt = canvas.toDataURL('PathPlanner/jpeg');`
```

this method gets wrong mime-type, thus it produces PNG as default, which should be `'image/jpeg'`, and the result will be like that:

```
var dt = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
```