# How to get usable canvas from Mapbox GL JS

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using [Mapbox GL](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js), and trying to get a snapshot of it, and merge the snapshot with another image overlaid for output.

I have a `HTMLCanvasElement` off screen, and I'm first writing the canvas returned from `Map.getCanvas()` to it, then writing the second (alpha transparent) canvas over that.

The problem is that, though I clearly see elements onscreen in the Map instance, the result only shows the second image/canvas written, and the rest is blank.

So I export just the map's canvas, and I see it is because the map canvas is blank, although a `console.log()` shows the image data from it to be a large chunk of information.

Here's my export function:

```
  onExport(annotationCanvas: HTMLCanvasElement) {

    const mergeCanvas: HTMLCanvasElement = document.createElement('canvas');
    const mapCanvas: HTMLCanvasElement = this.host.map.getCanvas();
    const mergeCtx: CanvasRenderingContext2D = mergeCanvas.getContext('2d');

    mergeCanvas.height = annotationCanvas.height;
    mergeCanvas.width = annotationCanvas.width;
    mergeCtx.drawImage(mapCanvas, 0, 0);
    mergeCtx.drawImage(annotationCanvas, 0, 0);

    const mergedDataURL = mergeCanvas.toDataURL();
    const mapDataURL = mapCanvas.toDataURL();
    const annotationDataURL = annotationCanvas.toDataURL();

    console.log(mapDataURL); // Lots of data

    download(mapDataURL, 'map-data-only.png'); // Blank image @ 1920x1080
    download(mergedDataURL, 'annotation.png'); // Only shows annotation (the second layer/canvas) data

  }
```

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

UPDATE: **I sort of figured out what this is about, and have possible  options.**

Upon stumbling upon a [Mapbox feature request](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/6448), I learned that if you instantiate your `Map` with the `preserveDrawingBuffer` option set to `false` (the default), you wont be able to get a canvas with usable image data. But setting this option to `true` degrades performance. But you can't change this setting after a Map is instantiated...

**I want the Map to perform the best it possibly can!!!!**

So, on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30647502/1253298) I stumbled on, regarding a question about three.js, I learned that if I take the screenshot immediately after rendering, I will get the canvas/data that I need.

I tried just calling `this.host.map['_rerender']()` right before I capture the canvas, but it still returned blankness.

Then searching around in the source code, I found a function called `_requestRenderFrame`, that looks like it might be what I need, because I can ask the Map to run a function immediately after the next render cycle. But as I come to find out, for some reason, that function is [omitted in the compiled code, whilst present in the source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49808049/), apparently because it is only in the master, and not part of the release.

So I don't really have a satisfactory solution yet, so please let me know of any insights.

Comment: Have you tried `_requestRenderFrame` in Mapbox GL JS `master`?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: Do you have a solution yet? I am experiencing the same problem.

Comment: I don’t remember the outcome. I would start with Andew Harvey’s answer. If it works, please post it here as a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's functional code. Note that Mapbox uses WebGl to render, so `getContext('d2')` returns `null`. It's better to create a canvas element, get the context, and set the map with the `drawImage` function. I hope this helps.

```
  let mapEl = document.querySelector('.mapboxgl-canvas');
    let resizedCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    let resizedContext = resizedCanvas.getContext("2d");


    const isMapEmpty = mapEl.toDataURL() === "data:,";
    if (isMapEmpty) {
        console.log("The map is void");
    } else {
        console.log("The map has information");
    }

    resizedCanvas.height = "1035";
    resizedCanvas.width = "755";

    resizedContext.drawImage(mapEl, 0, 0, 755, 1035);
    let b64 = await mergeImages([
            {
                src: resizedCanvas.toDataURL(),
                x: 297,
                y: 16
            },
            {
                src: "/assets/anotherImage.png"
            }
        ]
    )
```

Answer (score 5):

As you mentioned in your updated question the solution is to set `preserveDrawingBuffer: true` upon Map initialisation.

To answer your updated question I think @jfirebaugh's answer at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/6448#issuecomment-378307311 sums it up very well:

> `preserveDrawingBuffer` can't be modified on the fly. It has to be set at the time the WebGL context is created, and that can have a negative effect on performance.
>
> It's rumored that you can grab the the canvas data URL immediately after rendering, without needing `preserveDrawingBuffer`, but I haven't verified that, and I suspect it's not guaranteed by the spec.

So although it might be possible to grab the canvas data URL immediately after rendering, it's not guaranteed by the spec.