# In a compiled node module, why do I see (private) methods omitted from the compiled version that exist in the source?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, node-modules, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using Mapbox GL JS, and I've found a private method that might be useful in solving a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49807311/how-to-get-usable-canvas-from-mapbox-gl-js). It's [`_requestRenderFrame`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/13ea16df5eabc4c8867d69e81da180cdcd6cc6b2/src/ui/map.js#L1538) in map.js, and looks like this:

```
/**
 * Request that the given callback be executed during the next render
 * frame.  Schedule a render frame if one is not already scheduled.
 * @returns An id that can be used to cancel the callback
 * @private
 */
_requestRenderFrame(callback: () => void): TaskID {
    this._update();
    return this._renderTaskQueue.add(callback);
}
```

If I try to reference it in my project, I get `undefined`.

```
console.log(this.host.map['_requestRenderFrame']) // undefined;
```

When I search the `mapbox` package within my `node_modules` folder, I only see results for `"_requestRenderFrame"` in `dist/mapbox-gl-dev.js.map`.

There's other stuff that goes along with this feature that's not in there, so I can't really just hack the method back in on the fly.

I'm missing something. How can a method in source be omitted from compiled code? I have a hunch it may be just for testing??? But still, is there any way for me to use the omitted feature?

Comment: Just checking you're using master since that method was only added recently so isn't in a release https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/6328

Comment: Ah ha! K, I was looking at the version numbers, and they matched. So, that never ever even crossed my mind. So silly.