# How can I display some text in the top right corner of a Mapbox map?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

It looks to me like labels are meant to be anchored to objects in the map. In this case, I want to display some text on top of the map all of time.

I want it to be in the webgl itself, not an html element on top of it.

Comment: Relevant, but I am not sure if they found a definitive answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49807311/how-to-get-usable-canvas-from-mapbox-gl-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably a million different ways to better accomplish your REAL objective, if you'd only state what that is, but anyway, if you're really determined to do what your question states...

1. Make an image with your text.
2. Base64 Encode that image.
3. Initialize the map with `preserveDrawingBuffer: true` (note, performance will suffer)
4. Use the following code. Replace the long base64 string with YOUR image. Replace the token with YOUR token.

```
    // TO MAKE THE MAP APPEAR YOU MUST
    // ADD YOUR ACCESS TOKEN FROM
    // https://account.mapbox.com
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'REPLACEME';
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map', // container ID
        // Choose from Mapbox's core styles, or make your own style with Mapbox Studio
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // style URL
        center: [-74.5, 40], // starting position [lng, lat]
        zoom: 9, // starting zoom
        projection: 'globe', // display the map as a 3D globe,
        preserveDrawingBuffer: true
    });

    map.on('render', () => {
      var img, tex, vloc, tloc, vertexBuff, texBuff;
      var cvs3d = map.getCanvas();
       var ctx3d  = cvs3d.getContext("experimental-webgl");
       
       var uLoc;
        ctx3d.pixelStorei(ctx3d.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true); 
    // create shaders
    var vertexShaderSrc = `
        attribute vec2 aVertex;
        attribute vec2 aUV;
        varying vec2 vTex;
        uniform vec2 pos;
        void main(void) {
            gl_Position = vec4(aVertex + pos, 0.0, 1.0);
            vTex = aUV;
        }`;

    var fragmentShaderSrc = `
        precision highp float;
        varying vec2 vTex;
        uniform sampler2D sampler0;
        void main(void){
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(sampler0, vTex);
        }`;

    var vertShaderObj = ctx3d.createShader(ctx3d.VERTEX_SHADER);
    var fragShaderObj = ctx3d.createShader(ctx3d.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    ctx3d.shaderSource(vertShaderObj, vertexShaderSrc);
    ctx3d.shaderSource(fragShaderObj, fragmentShaderSrc);
    ctx3d.compileShader(vertShaderObj);
    ctx3d.compileShader(fragShaderObj);

    var progObj = ctx3d.createProgram();
    ctx3d.attachShader(progObj, vertShaderObj);
    ctx3d.attachShader(progObj, fragShaderObj);

    ctx3d.linkProgram(progObj);
    ctx3d.useProgram(progObj);

    ctx3d.viewport(0, 0, 64, 64);
  
    vertexBuff = ctx3d.createBuffer();
    ctx3d.bindBuffer(ctx3d.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuff);
    ctx3d.bufferData(ctx3d.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([-1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1]), ctx3d.STATIC_DRAW);

    texBuff = ctx3d.createBuffer();
    ctx3d.bindBuffer(ctx3d.ARRAY_BUFFER, texBuff);
    ctx3d.bufferData(ctx3d.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]), ctx3d.STATIC_DRAW);

    vloc = ctx3d.getAttribLocation(progObj, 'aVertex');
    tloc = ctx3d.getAttribLocation(progObj, 'aUV');
    uLoc = ctx3d.getUniformLocation(progObj, 'pos');

    var drawImage = function(imgobj, x, y, w, h) {
        tex = ctx3d.createTexture();
        ctx3d.bindTexture(ctx3d.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
        ctx3d.texParameteri(ctx3d.TEXTURE_2D, ctx3d.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, ctx3d.NEAREST);
        ctx3d.texParameteri(ctx3d.TEXTURE_2D, ctx3d.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, ctx3d.NEAREST);
        ctx3d.texImage2D(ctx3d.TEXTURE_2D, 0, ctx3d.RGBA, ctx3d.RGBA, ctx3d.UNSIGNED_BYTE, imgobj);

        ctx3d.enableVertexAttribArray(vloc);
        ctx3d.bindBuffer(ctx3d.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuff);
        ctx3d.vertexAttribPointer(vloc, 2, ctx3d.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        ctx3d.enableVertexAttribArray(tloc);
        ctx3d.bindBuffer(ctx3d.ARRAY_BUFFER, texBuff);
        ctx3d.bindTexture(ctx3d.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
        ctx3d.vertexAttribPointer(tloc, 2, ctx3d.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    ctx3d.drawArrays(ctx3d.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
    
    };

    img = new Image();
    img.src = 'data:image/png;base64,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';

    img.onload = function() {
        drawImage(this, 0, 0, 64, 64);

        var img2 = new Image();
        img2.src = 'data:image/png;base64,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';
        img2.onload = function() {
            drawImage(img2, 64-16, 64-16, 16, 16); // draw in bottom right corner
        }
    };
       
       
    });
```

Fiddle (you have to change map token in order to see it in action): https://jsfiddle.net/rygj51ca/1/

The above code will render an image of a smiley on the mapbox canvas, bottom left corner, every time the map renders.
[image]

Comment: THANK YOU for the response. The bounty expired before I could award it to you, is there some other way to transfer credit to you?

Comment: I have asked this question with more context here. I apologize for not asking with proper context initially, and would really appreciate it if you could help out! : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74409133/how-can-i-show-the-distance-a-polyline-has-covered-while-animating-it-in-mapbox

Comment: @KeithCarter, if it answers your question, you should mark it as accepted.

Answer (score -1):

If you want text in "the top right corner", then you don't want it *in* the map at all, you want it *over* the map.

In that case, the best way is just to use a different HTML element, styled however you like. Along these lines:

```
<div id="map" />
<div id="text-overlay" style="position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0;>Here's my text</div>
```

Comment: I specifically said I want the text to appear in the webgl itself, not an html element on top of it. I am capturing the webgl to record video and I want the text to appear in the video.

Comment: So, you didn't mention the actual *reason* you want this in your question.

Comment: Do you know how to do what I intend?

Comment: I'm pretty confident there is no way to do this in Mapbox GL JS, so it comes down to hacking the Web GL context directly.