# Three.JS using mesh to render two scene examples

Tags: javascript, three.js

I was not able to join two of the threejs examples. I am trying to join WebGL_animation_skinning_blending with the particles random example.

I found two helper websites and when rendering Chrome dev tools do not show errors (only warnings).

Rendering failed but it showed warnings.

> [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'wheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
<body><div id="info">test3b</div>

    <div id="container"></div>

    <script src="three.js"></script>

    <script src="js/renderers/Projector.js"></script>
    <script src="js/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js"></script>

    <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/dat.gui.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    //notes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26362816/three-js-renderer-autoclear-property-not-working
    //helpers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666570/how-to-change-the-zorder-of-object-with-threejs/12666937#12666937

        var container;
        var camera, scene, renderer, group, particle;
        //renderer.autoClear = false;

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true, preserveDrawingBuffer: true});

        scene = new THREE.Scene(); //scene2
        scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x333333 );
        scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff ) );
        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

        if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
        var container = document.getElementById( 'container' );//container2
        var controls;
        var mesh, skeleton, mixer;
        var crossFadeControls = [];
        var idleAction, walkAction, runAction;
        var idleWeight, walkWeight, runWeight;
        var actions;
        var settings;
        var clock = new THREE.Clock();
        var singleStepMode = false;
        var sizeOfNextStep = 0;
        var url = 'models/skinned/marine/marine_anims_core.json';


        // Initialize scene, light and renderer
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
        renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        container.appendChild( renderer.domElement ); //container2

        // Load skinned mesh
        new THREE.ObjectLoader().load( url, function ( loadedObject ) {
            loadedObject.traverse( function ( child ) {
                if ( child instanceof THREE.SkinnedMesh ) {
                    mesh = child;
                }
            } );
            if ( mesh === undefined ) {
                alert( 'Unable to find a SkinnedMesh in this place:\n\n' + url + '\n\n' );
                return;
            }
            // Add mesh and skeleton helper to scene
            mesh.rotation.y = - 135 * Math.PI / 180;
            scene.add( mesh );//scene2
            skeleton = new THREE.SkeletonHelper( mesh );
            skeleton.visible = false;
            scene.add( skeleton );//scene2
            // Initialize camera and camera controls
            var radius = mesh.geometry.boundingSphere.radius;
            var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, aspect, 1, 10000 );
            camera.position.set( 0.0, radius, radius * 3.5 );
            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
            controls.target.set( 0, radius, 0 );
            controls.update();
            // Create the control panel
            createPanel();
            //callsoldier();

            // Initialize mixer and clip actions
            mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( mesh );
            idleAction = mixer.clipAction( 'idle' );
            walkAction = mixer.clipAction( 'walk' );
            runAction = mixer.clipAction( 'run' );
            actions = [ idleAction, walkAction, runAction ];
            activateAllActions();
            // Listen on window resizing and start the render loop
            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
            //init();

                    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                    document.body.appendChild( container );

                    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 3000 );
                    camera.position.z = 1000;


                    var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
                    var program = function ( context ) {

                        context.beginPath();
                        context.arc( 0, 0, 0.5, 0, PI2, true );
                        context.fill();

                    };

                    group = new THREE.Group();
                    scene.add( group );

                    for ( var i = 0; i < 1000; i++ ) {

                        var material = new THREE.SpriteCanvasMaterial( {
                            color: Math.random() * 0x808008 + 0x808080,
                            program: program
                        } );

                        particle = new THREE.Sprite( material );
                        particle.position.x = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
                        particle.position.y = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
                        particle.position.z = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
                        particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = Math.random() * 20 + 10;
                        group.add( particle );
                    }

                    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
                    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
                    //container.appendChild( renderer2.domElement );


                    document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
                    document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false );
                    document.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false );

                    //

                    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            animate();
        } );



        function onWindowResize() {

            windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        //

        function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

            mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
            mouseY = event.clientY - windowHalfY;
        }

        function onDocumentTouchStart( event ) {

            if ( event.touches.length === 1 ) {

                event.preventDefault();

                mouseX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
                mouseY = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - windowHalfY;

            }

        }

        function onDocumentTouchMove( event ) {

            if ( event.touches.length === 1 ) {

                event.preventDefault();

                mouseX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
                mouseY = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - windowHalfY;

            }

        }


        function createPanel() {
            var panel = new dat.GUI( { width: 310 } );
            // var folder1 = panel.addFolder( 'Visibility' );
            // var folder2 = panel.addFolder( 'Activation/Deactivation' );
            // var folder3 = panel.addFolder( 'Pausing/Stepping' );
            var folder4 = panel.addFolder( 'Crossfading' );
            //var folder5 = panel.addFolder( 'Blend Weights' );
            var folder6 = panel.addFolder( 'General Speed' );
            settings = {
                'show model':            true,
                'show skeleton':         false,
                'deactivate all':        deactivateAllActions,
                'activate all':          activateAllActions,
                'pause/continue':        pauseContinue,
                'make single step':      toSingleStepMode,
                'modify step size':      0.05,
                'from walk to idle':     function () { prepareCrossFade( walkAction, idleAction, 1.0 ) },
                'from idle to walk':     function () { prepareCrossFade( idleAction, walkAction, 0.5 ) },
                'from walk to run':      function () { prepareCrossFade( walkAction, runAction, 2.5 ) },
                'from run to walk':      function () { prepareCrossFade( runAction, walkAction, 5.0 ) },
                'use default duration':  true,
                'set custom duration':   3.5,
                'modify idle weight':    0.0,
                'modify walk weight':    1.0,
                'modify run weight':     0.0,
                'modify time scale':     1.0
            };

            crossFadeControls.push( folder4.add( settings, 'from walk to idle' ) );
            crossFadeControls.push( folder4.add( settings, 'from idle to walk' ) );
            crossFadeControls.push( folder4.add( settings, 'from walk to run' ) );
            crossFadeControls.push( folder4.add( settings, 'from run to walk' ) );

            folder4.add( settings, 'set custom duration', 0, 10, 0.01 );

            folder6.add( settings, 'modify time scale', 0.0, 1.5, 0.01 ).onChange( modifyTimeScale );
            //folder1.open();
            //folder2.open();
            //folder3.open();
            folder4.open();
            //folder5.open();
            folder6.open();
            crossFadeControls.forEach( function ( control ) {
                control.classList1 = control.domElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList;
                control.classList2 = control.domElement.previousElementSibling.classList;
                control.setDisabled = function () {
                    control.classList1.add( 'no-pointer-events' );
                    control.classList2.add( 'control-disabled' );
                };
                control.setEnabled = function () {
                    control.classList1.remove( 'no-pointer-events' );
                    control.classList2.remove( 'control-disabled' );
                };
            } );
        }
        function showModel( visibility ) {
            mesh.visible = visibility;
        }
        function showSkeleton( visibility ) {
            skeleton.visible = visibility;
        }
        function modifyTimeScale( speed ) {
            mixer.timeScale = speed;
        }
        function deactivateAllActions() {
            actions.forEach( function ( action ) {
                action.stop();
            } );
        }
        function activateAllActions() {
            setWeight( idleAction, settings[ 'modify idle weight' ] );
            setWeight( walkAction, settings[ 'modify walk weight' ] );
            setWeight( runAction, settings[ 'modify run weight' ] );
            actions.forEach( function ( action ) {
                action.play();
            } );
        }
        function pauseContinue() {
            if ( singleStepMode ) {
                singleStepMode = false;
                unPauseAllActions();
            } else {
                if ( idleAction.paused ) {
                    unPauseAllActions();
                } else {
                    pauseAllActions();
                }
            }
        }
        function pauseAllActions() {
            actions.forEach( function ( action ) {
                action.paused = true;
            } );
        }
        function unPauseAllActions() {
            actions.forEach( function ( action ) {
                action.paused = false;
            } );
        }
        function toSingleStepMode() {
            unPauseAllActions();
            singleStepMode = true;
            sizeOfNextStep = settings[ 'modify step size' ];
        }
        function prepareCrossFade( startAction, endAction, defaultDuration ) {
            // Switch default / custom crossfade duration (according to the user's choice)
            var duration = setCrossFadeDuration( defaultDuration );
            // Make sure that we don't go on in singleStepMode, and that all actions are unpaused
            singleStepMode = false;
            unPauseAllActions();
            // If the current action is 'idle' (duration 4 sec), execute the crossfade immediately;
            // else wait until the current action has finished its current loop
            if ( startAction === idleAction ) {
                executeCrossFade( startAction, endAction, duration );
            } else {
                synchronizeCrossFade( startAction, endAction, duration );
            }
        }
        function setCrossFadeDuration( defaultDuration ) {
            // Switch default crossfade duration <-> custom crossfade duration
            if ( settings[ 'use default duration' ] ) {
                return defaultDuration;
            } else {
                return settings[ 'set custom duration' ];
            }
        }
        function synchronizeCrossFade( startAction, endAction, duration ) {
            mixer.addEventListener( 'loop', onLoopFinished );
            function onLoopFinished( event ) {
                if ( event.action === startAction ) {
                    mixer.removeEventListener( 'loop', onLoopFinished );
                    executeCrossFade( startAction, endAction, duration );
                }
            }
        }
        function executeCrossFade( startAction, endAction, duration ) {
            // Not only the start action, but also the end action must get a weight of 1 before fading
            // (concerning the start action this is already guaranteed in this place)
            setWeight( endAction, 1 );
            endAction.time = 0;
            // Crossfade with warping - you can also try without warping by setting the third parameter to false
            startAction.crossFadeTo( endAction, duration, true );
        }
        // This function is needed, since animationAction.crossFadeTo() disables its start action and sets
        // the start action's timeScale to ((start animation's duration) / (end animation's duration))
        function setWeight( action, weight ) {
            action.enabled = true;
            action.setEffectiveTimeScale( 1 );
            action.setEffectiveWeight( weight );
        }
        // Called by the render loop
        function updateWeightSliders() {
            settings[ 'modify idle weight' ] = idleWeight;
            settings[ 'modify walk weight' ] = walkWeight;
            settings[ 'modify run weight' ] = runWeight;
        }
        // Called by the render loop
        function updateCrossFadeControls() {
            crossFadeControls.forEach( function ( control ) {
                control.setDisabled();
            } );
            if ( idleWeight === 1 && walkWeight === 0 && runWeight === 0 ) {
                crossFadeControls[ 1 ].setEnabled();
            }
            if ( idleWeight === 0 && walkWeight === 1 && runWeight === 0 ) {
                crossFadeControls[ 0 ].setEnabled();
                crossFadeControls[ 2 ].setEnabled();
            }
            if ( idleWeight === 0 && walkWeight === 0 && runWeight === 1 ) {
                crossFadeControls[ 3 ].setEnabled();
            }
        }
        function onWindowResize() {
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        }



                    //renderer.autoClear = false; // important!
        function animate() {
            // Render loop
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            idleWeight = idleAction.getEffectiveWeight();
            walkWeight = walkAction.getEffectiveWeight();
            runWeight = runAction.getEffectiveWeight();
            // Update the panel values if weights are modified from "outside" (by crossfadings)
            updateWeightSliders();
            // Enable/disable crossfade controls according to current weight values
            updateCrossFadeControls();
            // Get the time elapsed since the last frame, used for mixer update (if not in single step mode)
            var mixerUpdateDelta = clock.getDelta();
            // If in single step mode, make one step and then do nothing (until the user clicks again)
            if ( singleStepMode ) {
                mixerUpdateDelta = sizeOfNextStep;
                sizeOfNextStep = 0;
            }
            // Update the animation mixer, the stats panel, and render this frame
            mixer.update( mixerUpdateDelta );
            //stats.update();


                //renderer.clear();
                //renderer.setViewport( 0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            //renderer.render( scene, camera );
            //renderer.clearDepth();
                                    //renderer.setViewport( 10, window.innerHeight - insetHeight - 10, insetWidth, insetHeight );
                            //camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * 0.01;
                            //camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * 0.01;
                            //camera.lookAt( scene.position );
                            //
                            //group.rotation.x += 0.0001;
                            //group.rotation.y += 0.0002;
            //renderer.render( scene2, camera );//render();

            mesh.renderOrder = 999;
            mesh.onBeforeRender = function( renderer ) { renderer.clearDepth(); };
        }


    </script>


</body>
```